# Problem with vector multiplication

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d

I have this plane problem and the answers are released for it. I don't understand this specific part: 
Why does : (i + 4k) x (3j - k) = -12i + j + 3k.

I tried using the cross product method, however, i am stuck and can't proceed on. Please explain the manner in which this is calculated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know that $i\times j = k$, $k\times j = -i$, $i\times k = -j$, $k\times k = 0$, etc.?

Comment: @alex Why is that so?

Comment: It just comes from the very definition of vectorial product.

Comment: @alex Hmmm..okay. Will read more about it. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Phantom. You might find this [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful :)

Comment: @Shaun Oh god! Thank you so much, i was so clueless on how to enter the maths problems properly. This helps, will be a better "poster", next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using matrix notation:

$$(i+4k)\times(3j-k)=\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k\\1&0&4\\0&3&\!\!-1\end{vmatrix}=(0-12)i+(0+1)j+(3-0)k=-12i+j+3k$$

Comment: Ah...so we place 0, wherever there is no value specified

Comment: Well, yes. In mathematical (as opposed to physical) notation, we have that $\;i+4k=(1,0,4)\;$ , say.

Comment: Okay! I understand it now, i was stuck because i didn't know how to proceed on without a value for the i and j. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First, expand it out:

$$(i + 4k)\times(3j-k) = 3(i\times{j}) + 12(k\times{j}) - (i\times{k}) - 4(k\times{k})$$

But $i\times{j} = k, k\times{j} = -i,i\times{k} = -j, k\times{k} = 0$. These can be deduced from the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the standard basis vectors $i,j,k$. Hence,

$$(i + 4k)\times(3j-k) = 3k -12i +j$$

Rearranging,

$$(i + 4k)\times(3j-k) = -12i + j + 3k$$